# why the value inside 'if statement' in java cannot be accessed outside of 'if statement'?

Tags: java

following code is giving error message as 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The local variable answer may not have been initialized'.

```
package firstproject;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class calculator {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        double firstno, secondno, answer;
        int choice;
        Scanner add = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What r u trying to do??");
        System.out.println("1 - add");
        System.out.println("2 - substract");
        System.out.println("3 - multiplication");
        System.out.println("4 - division");

        choice = add.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter your 1st number: ");
        firstno = add.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter another number: ");
        secondno = add.nextDouble();

        if(choice == 1){
            answer = firstno + secondno;
        }
        if(choice == 2){
            answer = firstno - secondno;
        }
        if(choice == 3){
            answer = firstno * secondno;
        }
        if(choice == 4){
            answer = firstno / secondno;
        }

        System.out.println("answer: " + answer);
    }
}
```

so, i did something like this

```
package firstproject;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class calculator {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        double firstno, secondno, answer;
        int choice;
        Scanner add = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What r u trying to do??");
        System.out.println("1 - add");
        System.out.println("2 - substract");
        System.out.println("3 - multiplication");
        System.out.println("4 - division");

        choice = add.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter your 1st number: ");
        firstno = add.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter another number: ");
        secondno = add.nextDouble();

        if(choice == 1){
            answer = firstno + secondno;
            System.out.println("Answer: " + answer);
        }
        if(choice == 2){
            answer = firstno - secondno;
            System.out.println("Answer: " + answer);
        }
        if(choice == 3){
            answer = firstno * secondno;
            System.out.println("Answer: " + answer);
        }
        if(choice == 4){
            answer = firstno / secondno;
            System.out.println("Answer: " + answer);
        }
    }
}
```

it worked. but i want to know why my first code didn't work.

Comment: Because `answer` isn't guaranteed to have a value when it's used at the end of the method.

Comment: Think about what happens if `choice` is `5`, when you get to `System.out.println("answer: " + answer);`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *can* access it, but if none of your conditions was `true`, `answer` will not be initialized when you are trying to print it.

Initialize it with  `double answer = 0`.

Comment: Well, initializing it with a value is *one* option - but it's not necessarily the most helpful one. Maybe the right thing to do if the choice isn't matched is return from the method, or throw an exception, or do something else.

Comment: Explicitly initializing a variable is never a bad choice. However, the question was not about the best way how to deal with the problem (--> Code Review), but why the exception occurs.

Comment: I disagree - it *is* a bad practice if that value is never desired. The code is misleading, and should be refactored to ensure that there is no attempt to read it without assigning a meaningful value.

Answer (score 3):

Local variables in Java can't be read unless they're [*definitely assigned*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-16.html) - in other words, if the compiler can *prove* that every way that you can get to the expression that's trying to read the variable will have gone through an assignment to that variable.

In your case, if `choice` isn't 1, 2, 3 or 4 you won't have gone through an assignment.

Ways of fixing this:

- Specify an initial value as part of the variable declaration
- Change your `if` series to an `if/else` series with a plain `else` at the end, which either terminates the method or assigns a value. For example:

  ```
  if (choice == 1) {
      answer = firstno + secondno;
  } else if (choice == 2) {
      answer = firstno - secondno;
  } else  if (choice == 3) {
      answer = firstno * secondno;
  } else if(choice == 4) {
      answer = firstno / secondno;
  } else {
      System.out.println("Invalid choice");
      return; // Or assign a value to answer
  }
  ```
- Use a `switch` statement instead of your `if` statements, and provide a `default` case which either assigns to `answer` or returns

Comment: i know switch statement and i had already tried if else statement but it didn't work but 'return' did a trick. and i want to ask you what did 'return' actually  did there???

Comment: @Nawa: That's the only path in which `answer` isn't assigned - so by the time you get to `System.out.println("answer: " + answer);`, every path which *can* get there *does* assign a value to `answer`... it's *definitely assigned* at that point.

Answer (score 0):

if all the conditions in all ifs are false, the variable answer will indeed not be initialized.

Say choice is 42245234, what value does answer have in this line?

```
System.out.println("answer: " + answer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the `answer` with some values like `answer=-1` before printing, **because how we can print a null reference**

> once any variable initialized it can be use in body of conditional statements

suppose **You don't enter valid choice** , what would be the value in `answer` , while `answer` is just act like a **null reference**

Answer (score 0):

"The local variable answer may not have been initialized" is accurate.  If the user types in "5", then answer doesn't get set to any value.  Try defining answer as "answer = 0.0".

Answer (score 0):

1. The var "answer" may not be inited if "choice" does not belong to "1,2,3,4". So when you try to print it at the very end, this exception may happen.
2. The second one actually has the same problem, the only reason that makes it work is you moved the print line up to each blocks. So when "choice" does not belong to "1,2,3,4", the code needs to do nothing. And it will be considered as "No problem".
3. For the fix, all of them above :)